# Is exists any way to calculate the parameter of attribute dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net

Exists some imported function. It is used in the AutoCAD 2009 plugin. But for newer AutoCAD versions it is to use `acdb18.dll`, `acdb19.dll` and `acdb20.dll`.
Of course, I can add the similar import record for each AutoCAD version, but maybe exist more convenient way with dynamic replacing 18, 19, or 20 instead of 17? I think it is not possible, but I ask my question for to be sure.

```
[DllImport("acdb17.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
EntryPoint = "?acdbSetDbmod@@YAJPAVAcDbDatabase@@J@Z")]
private static extern Int32 acdbSetDbmod17x86(IntPtr db, Int32 newDbMod);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot calculate the attribute parameters, these are embedded in a different way than for normal executing code and has to be constant.

Instead you should create 4 distinct methods, one for each such library, and have the surrounding code figure out which one to call.

ie. something like this:

```
[DllImport("acdb17.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
EntryPoint = "?acdbSetDbmod@@YAJPAVAcDbDatabase@@J@Z")]
private static extern Int32 v17_acdbSetDbmod17x86(IntPtr db, Int32 newDbMod);

[DllImport("acdb18.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
EntryPoint = "?acdbSetDbmod@@YAJPAVAcDbDatabase@@J@Z")]
private static extern Int32 v18_acdbSetDbmod17x86(IntPtr db, Int32 newDbMod);

switch (version)
{
    case 17: v17_acdbSetDbmod17x86(...);
    case 18: v18_acdbSetDbmod17x86(...);
             ^-+^
               |
               +-- notice the prefix to the methods
```

Or, you should create 4 distinct classes all implementing the same interface and pick the right class at startup:

```
public class AutoCADAPI17 : IAutoCADAPI
{
    ....

public class AutoCADAPI18 : IAutoCADAPI
{
    ....
```

This way you would just pick the right implementation once and go to the right methods each time without having to switch.

Comment: Yes, I know this way, but I had a faint hope that some *magic way* exists. :) Thank you.